# How I can get parameter by $_GET

Tags: php, html, utf-8

I can not get parameter `$_GET` with it value contain character: '#'.

I have the follow code:

```
<iframe src="http://localhost/wp352/wp-content/plugins/heloworld/templates/options-rte.php?text_content=<span style="color: #ff0000;">Empty content.</span>">
```

and when I change or eliminate the character: '#' all work fine. for example:

```
<iframe src="http://localhost/wp352/wp-content/plugins/heloworld/templates/options-rte.php?text_content=<span style="color: ff0000;">Empty content.</span>">
```

How I can get the parameter (text_content) value complete?

Note: I'm testing in **PHP** get this parameter/value `$_GET['text_content']`.

Thanks

Comment: Try encoding the url with `url_encode`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to urlencode() any strings you pass in through GET requests and urldecode() them once you grab them from $_GET.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

The quotes in your string are also causing issues. Try this for your top iframe:

```
<iframe src="http://localhost/wp352/wp-content/plugins/heloworld/templates/options-rte.php?text_content=%3Cspan%20style%3D%22color%3A%20%23ff0000%3B%22%3EEmpty%20content.%3C%2Fspan%3E">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use  [url_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)  function, because whatever comes after `#` won't be considered as part of URL(browsers don't send that part to server).

Answer (score 0):

You should really use urlencode before sending it to your php script for handling, and then use urldecode to output it normally.

Maybe try:

```
<iframe src="<?php urlencode('http://localhost/wp352/wp-content/plugins/heloworld/templates/options-rte.php?text_content=<span style="color: #ff0000;">Empty content.</span>'); ?>">
```

to fetch it:

```
urldecode($_GET['text_content']);
```

Comment: You also don't need to urlencode everything, just the parameters being passed into the script.

Comment: Please note that you should `urlencode` only the passed value not the whole link. `urlencode` will encode `/` to be `%2F` which will result in a broken link.